# Word generation with nested loops

Tags: shell-script

I made this script which generates all combinations of lowercase letters and numbers and echoes them. It works, but I am wondering if there is a way to simplify the process of adding a new char instead of my current way of having to make a new function for every new character I want to add. Here's my script:

```
declare -r LIST=$(echo {a..z} {0..9})

function word_generation_2 {
    for char1 in  ${LIST}; do
        for char2 in  ${LIST}; do
            echo ${char1}${char2}
        done
    done
}

function word_generation_3 {
    for char1 in  ${LIST}; do
        for char2 in  ${LIST}; do
            for char3 in  ${LIST}; do
                echo ${char1}${char2}${char3}
            done
        done
    done
}


function word_generation_4 {
    for char1 in  ${LIST}; do
        for char2 in  ${LIST}; do
            for char3 in  ${LIST}; do
                for char4 in  ${LIST}; do
                    echo ${char1}${char2}${char3}${char4}
                done
            done
        done
    done
}


function word_generation_5 {
    for char1 in  ${LIST}; do
        for char2 in  ${LIST}; do
            for char3 in  ${LIST}; do
                for char4 in  ${LIST}; do
                    for char5 in  ${LIST}; do
                         echo ${char1}${char2}${char3}${char4}${char5}
                    done
                done
            done
        done
    done
}


for ((i = 2; i < 6; i++)); do
    word_generation_${i}
done
```

Output is:

```
aa

...


99999
```

I want to keep it like that. First all combinations of 2 chars, then all combinations of 3 chars, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bash or something that supports [arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html), you could put the character set in an array and loop over the array again, prepending the characters again:

```
chars=( {a,b,c} )
doubles=()
triplets=()
for c in "${chars[@]}" ; do 
    doubles+=( ${chars[@]/#/$c} )
done
for c in "${chars[@]}" ; do 
    triplets+=( ${doubles[@]/#/$c} )
done
echo "${triplets[@]}"
```

that prints `aaa aab aac ... ccc`, and you can repeat as necessary for the longer ones, or turn it into a recursive function. (The `${var//}` is a [pattern substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) where `#` marks the start of the string. When it's applied to an array, it applies to *all* values of the array, one at a time.)

Comment: Fantastic code right here! thank you. I don't quite get how to print longer chains of characters. How would I print combinations of 3 or 4 characters?

Comment: loop over `chars` again and append to `doubles` this time, edited

Comment: I've seen that in the first for loop you can actually write:

Comment: doubles+=( ${chars[@]/#/$c} )
triplets+=( ${chars[@]/#/$c$c} )

So you don't need new for loops.

Last thing is the code prints the output alltogether while I wanted it to be written one combination per line. Any suggestion for this?

Comment: doubles+=( ${chars[@]/#/$c} ) how does it working, someone explain me..

Comment: @B.P.R., if you do `triplets+=( ${chars[@]/#/$c$c} )`, you add the same character twice, so you'd get `aa`, and `bb`, but not `ab` or `ba`. As for printing with newlines, either loop over the array and `echo`, or use `printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}"` (it takes a C-style format string and repeats it as many times as necessary to use all arguments)

Comment: @balajibalu, `${chars[@]}` expands to all values in the array `chars`, `${variable/a/b}` performs text substition (`a` changed to `b`), and `+= ( ... )` just appends to the array. Take a peek at links in the answer, the Bash reference manual is quite readable.

Comment: I've tried triplets+=( ${chars[@]/#/$c$c} ) and when echoing doubles it shows correctly: aa, ab, ac, ad... and when echoing triplets it echoes: aaa, aab, aac, etc. so I think all god. Thanks for your answers